# Switch power supply between battery and charger

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I've been working on an application with ESP32-CAM. One of the requirements for this application is that the ESP32-CAM should never turn off. To achieve this, I've tried using a system with a lithium battery (5000mAh) and a charger (5V - VBUS). The main idea is that when the charger is not connected, the circuit should be powered by the lithium battery. In both cases (battery or charger), I need to regulate the voltage to 3.3V and power the ESP32-CAM. I attempted to accomplish this using a system with a P-channel MOSFET (Q2 and Q3), as shown below.

The circuit is working in a general context, but I currently have a major issue with my application. When I remove the charger, the switching time is too long, and the ESP32-CAM ends up restarting. I measured the voltage at the ESP32-CAM (3V3_ESP - Yellow) and the voltage at the input of the 3.3V regulator (DVDD4V2 - Green). The voltage drop that causes the ESP32-CAM to restart takes approximately 500ms.

Oscilloscope image - Points 3V3_ESP (Yellow) and DVDD4V2 (Green)
[image]

VBUS (5V) coming from a USB type C

[image]

Charger circuit
[image]

Regulators and measuring points
[image]

Some things that I tried to reduce or eliminate this delay were:

Increasing the capacitance in 3V3_ESP -> It didn't work. There were no significant changes.

Decreasing the resistance of R20 and R22 (from 100 ohms to 10 ohms) -> It didn't work.

Changing D7 to one with a lower VF (forward voltage) -> It didn't work. There were no significant changes.

I wonder how laptop and mobile systems make the change from charger to battery in their applications. I'm thinking of changing the partnumber of the Q2 and Q3 mosfets. Use specific mosfets for fast switching.

Has anyone worked with a similar system? Any comment is welcome.

Comment: Did you mean cutting VBUS (USB) with `When I remove the charger`?

Comment: @RohatKılıç Exactly, when VBUS is 0V.

Comment: Did you try by shorting VBUS to ground, instead of removing the connection and leaving it floating? I'm asking this because, as can be seen from the MOSFET CONTROL block, if VBUS is floating it'll take longer for the Q2 to turn on i.e. presumably a very small amount of leakage (through the input impedance of TP4056, say Rtp) will charge the G-S capacitor of the Q2 to VV_BUS, make Vgs negative enough and turn Q2 on - T = Rtp x Ciss. If Rtp is too large T will be too long.

Comment: I hadn't tried to do this until then. Now I put a pulldown resistor between VBUS and GND (330R). The interrupt time drops to 37ms. I think with your idea I'm on the right way.